# Place objects by clicking a canvas

Tags: arrays, class, object, click, processing

Hello. I am new to SO. I have an assignment, which requires me to allow a user to click on a canvas and place an object. The user is only allowed to place the object 100 times and anywhere on the canvas. The problem is I can only create one object and it always goes to the upper left corner.

Here is my code:

```
Food[] f;


void setup()
{
  size(400,400);
  background(206,172,26);

  f = new Food[100];
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    f[i] = new Food();    
}

void draw()
{
  for(int i=0; i<f.length; i++)
    f[i].draw(); 
}

 class Food
 {
  color c;
  int xpos;
  int ypos;

    Food() 
  {
    c = color(0,255,0);
   xpos = mouseX;
   ypos = mouseY;    
 }
   void draw()
  {
    if (mousePressed == true)
   {
     fill(c);
     ellipse(xpos,ypos,10,10);
   }       
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for an ArrayList, so you can easily add objects:

```
ArrayList<Dummy> d = new ArrayList<Dummy>();

void setup(){
  size (400, 400);
  smooth();

}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  for(Dummy dd:d){
    dd.display();
  }
}

void mouseReleased(){
  if(d.size() < 100)
  d.add(new Dummy(mouseX, mouseY));

  println(d.size());
}

class Dummy{
  int x, y;
  Dummy(int _x, int _y){
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
  }

  void display(){
   ellipse(x,y,10,10);
  }


}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, a_schimpf and v.k.

Comment: It's good to start early using ArrayLists. Makes everything so much easier down the line.

Comment: +1 on using ArrayLists early. They make many things much simpler when you have to start adding and removing elements. They are imo just as easy as arrays once you memorize the slightly different syntax for iteration.

Comment: don't forget linkedlists.  they're faster at inserting/removing. arraylists are faster at accessing elements.

Answer (score 3):

Your Food() constructor does not have parameters for the xpos and ypos of the mouse.  You should change it to be:

```
Food(int mousePosX, int mousePosY)
{
    xpos = mousePosX;
    ypos = mousePosY;
}
```

Also, you should create a Food object only when you click.  Then you can get the position of the mouse and pass that into the Food object constructor. You will need a counter to keep track of how many food objects you have created.

All that said, you should do homework on your own (unless you are **REALLY** stuck).  You learn better.